# Find remaining outer rectangles from Rectangle.Intersection

Tags: c#, system.drawing

I have an outer rectangle and a rectangle inside. How can I return all remaining rectangle after cut of intersecting rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The natural way to represent this would be to use the [`Region` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.region(v=vs.110).aspx), something like:

```
var result = new Region(outer);
result.Exclude(inner);
```

If you really want a list of `Rectangle` structures, you can look at converting to `RectangleF`s using `GetRegionScans` using an identity matrix and then converting them to `Rectangle`s using `Ceiling` or `Floor`.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this function that return a List excluding the intersecting one.

```
 private IEnumerable<Rectangle> GetExternalRectangles(Rectangle surface, Rectangle test)
    {
        var result = new List<Rectangle>();

        if (!test.IntersectsWith(surface)) return new List<Rectangle> { surface };
        #region Top and Bottom

        if (test.Top>surface.Top && test.Bottom < surface.Bottom) // test inside surface vertically
        {
            result.Add(new Rectangle(surface.Location, new Size(surface.Width, test.Top - surface.Top)));
            result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(surface.Left,test.Bottom), new Size(surface.Width, surface.Bottom-test.Bottom)));
        }
        if (test.Top > surface.Top && test.Bottom > surface.Bottom) // test inside surface vertically, overflow bottom
        {
            result.Add(new Rectangle(surface.Location, new Size(surface.Width, test.Top - surface.Top)));
            //result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(surface.Left,test.Bottom), new Size(surface.Width, surface.Bottom-test.Bottom)));
        }
        if (test.Top < surface.Top && test.Bottom < surface.Bottom) // test inside surface vertically, overflow top
        {
            //result.Add(new Rectangle(surface.Location, new Size(surface.Width, test.Top - surface.Top)));
            result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(surface.Left, test.Bottom), new Size(surface.Width, surface.Bottom - test.Bottom)));
        }

        #endregion

        #region Lateral
        if (test.Left > surface.Left && test.Right < surface.Right) // test inside surface horizontally
        {
            result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(surface.Left,Math.Max(surface.Top,test.Top)), new Size(test.Left-surface.Left, Math.Min(surface.Bottom, test.Bottom)- Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top))));
            result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(test.Right, Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top)), new Size(surface.Right - test.Right, Math.Min(surface.Bottom, test.Bottom) - Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top))));
        }
        if (test.Left > surface.Left && test.Right > surface.Right) // test inside surface horizontally, overflow right
        {
            result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(surface.Left, Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top)), new Size(test.Left - surface.Left, Math.Min(surface.Bottom, test.Bottom) - Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top))));
            //result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(test.Right, Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top)), new Size(surface.Right - test.Right, Math.Min(surface.Bottom, test.Bottom) - Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top))));
        }
        if (test.Left < surface.Left && test.Right < surface.Right) // test inside surface horizontally, overflow left
        {
            //result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(surface.Left, Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top)), new Size(test.Left - surface.Left, Math.Min(surface.Bottom, test.Bottom) - Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top))));
            result.Add(new Rectangle(new Point(test.Right, Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top)), new Size(surface.Right - test.Right, Math.Min(surface.Bottom, test.Bottom) - Math.Max(surface.Top, test.Top))));
        }
        #endregion
        return result;
    }
```